# Algebraic expression and factorisation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $x^4+\frac 1{x^4}=1$
Then find the value of $$x^{48}+x^{52}+x^{56}+x^{60}$$
My try ----make a quadratic equation and find x but that is too tedious. ...
I tried factorisation but didn't get anything. 
Please help.

Comment: There are lots of good identities to play with here.  For instance, multiplying by $x^{52}$ shows that $x^{56}+x^{48}=x^{52}$ Similarly $x^{60}+x^{52}=x^{56}$.  Adding these shows that your sum equals $x^{52}+x^{56}$ which implies that $x^{48}+x^{60}=0$.  Doesn't immediately solve your problem, but it seems like a promising start.

Comment: Plenty of "smart" answers, you could just find $x$ and then use a calculator.

Comment: As I said, plugging the value of x is not what I am looking for as it is quite tedious

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276746/given-that-x-frac1x-sqrt3-find-x18x24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{12}+1=(x^4+1)(x^8-x^4+1)=0.$$
Thus, $x^{48}+x^{60}=1-1=0$.

In another hand $x^{52}+x^{56}=x^{48}(x^4+x^8)=x^4+x^8=2x^4-1=\pm\sqrt3i$

Comment: But what about the other two terms?I did come to this stage but not the final solution

Comment: @Vindhyachal Vindhyachal I fixed. See now please.

Answer (score 2):

You might note that $x^{52}+x^{60} = x^{56}(\frac{1}{x^4}+x^4) = x^{56}.$  Similarly, $x^{48}+x^{56} = x^{52}.$   So your expression equals $x^{56}+x^{52}=x^{52}(x^4+1).$